# Java SWT library horrible layout in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, swt, windowbuilder

I developed a desktop application using SWT libraries for GUI.
Running the application on Windows 7 runs fine, the layout is clean.
I tried to run the same application on Windows 10 and it's a disaster!
Font enormous and cut windows, horrible!

I disabled the display scaling and put 100% in the view options but nothing, the problem remains.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks to those who want to help me.

```js
java,
```

```html
Snippet:

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class mySWTApp extends Shell {
 private Text txt_name;
 private Text txt_surname;

 /**
  * Launch the application.
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
   Display display = Display.getDefault();
   mySWTApp shell = new mySWTApp(display);
   shell.open();
   shell.layout();
   while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
     display.sleep();
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 /**
  * Create the shell.
  * @param display
  */
 public mySWTApp(Display display) {
  super(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
  setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_BACKGROUND_GRADIENT));
  setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
  setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
  
  Composite composite = new Composite(this, SWT.BORDER);
  composite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_BACKGROUND_GRADIENT));
  composite.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Tahoma", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
  composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
  composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
  
  Label lblNewLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
  lblNewLabel.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Tahoma", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
  lblNewLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
  lblNewLabel.setText("Name");
  
  txt_name = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
  txt_name.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
  
  Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
  lblNewLabel_1.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Tahoma", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
  lblNewLabel_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
  lblNewLabel_1.setText("Surname");
  
  txt_surname = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
  txt_surname.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
  
  Button btn_add = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
  btn_add.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Tahoma", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
  GridData gd_btn_add = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1);
  gd_btn_add.widthHint = 126;
  btn_add.setLayoutData(gd_btn_add);
  btn_add.setText("Insert");
  createContents();
 }

 /**
  * Create contents of the shell.
  */
 protected void createContents() {
  setText("Basic Name");
  setSize(450, 135);

 }

 @Override
 protected void checkSubclass() {
  // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide eclipse version. And a code snippet?

Comment: Could the problem be due to your settings in Win 8?

Comment: Eclipse Mars .2. SWT 4.5 stable version. Windowsbuilder lastest version.

Comment: Snippet added. Thanks again.

Comment: I've update my app using eclipse neon and SWT 4.6, but the result is the same :(

Comment: Since this exists in Windows 10 with neon as well, I suggest open a bug at bugs.eclipse.org. I already informed this to the person who manages SWT Windows port.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently, and thought it had to do with Windows 10. A bit of research revealed that the actual reason was the higher resolution of the new PC that came with Windows 10! There is quite a simple solution described at
[Perfectmobile community: Solution for eclipse with high resolution laptops](https://community.perfectomobile.com/posts/1135007-solution-for-eclipse-with-high-resolution-laptops).
I did as described, making sure to change the name of the downloaded manifest file to match the name of my application, and it worked just fine!
Useful information can also be found in this [Slideshow about scaling SWT on high-resolution screens](https://www.slideshare.net/da152/swt-scalingece2014-aktuell) on how to make your application dpiAware

Comment: Perfectmobile community: Solution for eclipse with high resolution laptops <--this links 404s